# When to release the model(representedObject) of the corresponding UIViewController

Tags: iphone, model-view-controller, uiviewcontroller, cocoa-bindings, cocoa-design-patterns

In AppKit we have "representedObject" available through `NSViewController`, this representedObject is generally set to ModelController or the model which the `NSViewController`  displays, this works great with bindings as you just set the new representedObject and model details are updated in the view, BUT in case of iPhone (UIKit, with NO Cocoa bindings available), there is no such representedObject in `UIViewController` so here are few things I am interested in knowing:-

1. What is the best/recommended way of binding the model to the UIViewController?, preferably dont want to maintain lot of `IBOutlets` and calls setters to updated the changed model data for display in view.
2. How/When should the related model of the UIViewController be released?
3. When is the `-[UIViewController dealloc]` called, in the typical iPhone application.

Am looking for architecting some classes so that the `UIViewController` coordinates between the view and the model, but at the same time, deallocs the model when ever not necessary.

TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the big problem with Cocoa bindings, it hides a lot of things that are very easy.

dealloc is called when the retain count reaches 0.  For a view controller that will happen when other controllers have released it and it doesn't have any other retains.  You shouldn't worry about this if you are doing memory management according to the rules.

Create a property for your model object, or model controller if you want to go to that level of abstraction.  Using the property correctly (like always using `self.model` for receiving assignments), and release the object in your dealloc implementation, and set it to nil in `viewWillUnload`.  Properties create the accessors for you.

As for releasing your model when not required, the above will handle that for you - there's no need to overthink it.  If you are creating massive data structures, then you can consider building them in `viewWillAppear` and tearing down in `viewWillDisappear` in addition to the above.

You will need more outlets and glue code than you would with bindings; but you'll have to write a lot less code to manage your bindings.  Remember that iPhone is supposed to be a less powerful device, and you are supposed to take greater care of resources - and the `UIViewController` api gives you the opportunities to do that.

Comment: Thanks Paull, I want to keep my methods KVC-KVO compliant so that in case iPhone adds bindings in future, its would be lesser work to switch.
The other thing I was thinking was to add some kind of caching so that I dont hit the remote servers every time(say in viewWillDisappear and viewWillAppear running some txns to get data), just thinking of some abstract architecture which can be later used by other too... Just thoughts.... Thx.